# XSLT template matching on //

Tags: xslt-2.0

The following xslt code produces the output incorrectly. Actually, it should increment the values by 1, But, It produces increment by 2. I need to get this know why. Could anyone let me know why this?

the xml input is

```
<AAA>
    <BBB>cc </BBB>
    <BBB>ff </BBB>
  <BBB>aa </BBB>
   <BBB>fff </BBB>
   <BBB>FFF </BBB>
  <BBB>Aa </BBB>
  <BBB>ccCCC </BBB>
</AAA>
```

and the xslt input code is

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>
BBB[</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
<xsl:text>]: </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

It produces the output as follows [wrongly], but it should provide such as [1], [2], [3] etc.

```
BBB[2]: cc 
BBB[4]: ff 
BBB[8]: aa 
BBB[10]: fff 
BBB[12]: FFF 
BBB[14]: Aa 
BBB[16]: ccCCC
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure if you only have `<xsl:template match="/">` that then you won't even get the output you say you get.
Assuming you have

```
<xsl:template match="BBB">
<xsl:text>
BBB[</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
<xsl:text>]: </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

then the result depends on other factors like whether you have `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` or whether you use

```
<xsl:template match="AAA">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Your current result you have suggests you are not stripping white space text nodes and you either rely on built-in templates or you have `<xsl:apply-templates/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` in the template matching `AAA`. That way the current node list contains both element node as well as text nodes (between element nodes) resulting in your position results 2, 4, 6, ...

I would fix the code with

```
<xsl:template match="BBB">
<xsl:text>
BBB[</xsl:text>
<xsl:number/>
<xsl:text>]: </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```